# how could I use sql 'case when' correctly in Athena

Tags: sql

```
select  
 (case "plm"."event" when ('newMessage' and plm.id == vm.id) then 'VoiceMessgae' else plm."event" end) as "event"
   FROM 
   others_messages plm
   left join voice_messages vm on plm.id = vm.id
```

it shows no viable alternative at input '(case "plm"."event" when ('newMessage' and plm.id =='

how could I fix it?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  Also, why doesn't your query work?

Comment: `==` is invalid SQL syntax. Use `=` for an equals comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be syntactically correct, the `case` expression would be:

```
select (case when "plm"."event" = 'newMessage' and plm.id = vm.id
             then 'VoiceMessgae'
             else plm."event"
        end) as "event"
```

`case` offers two syntaxes.  If you have complex expressions, you need to use the searched `case` where the boolean expression follows the `when`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select
    case when "plm"."event" = 'newMessage' and vm.id is not nulll
        then 'VoiceMessgae' 
        else plm."event" 
    end as "event" 
from others_messages plm 
left join voice_messages vm on plm.id = vm.id
```

You don't need to perfom the equality check in the `case` condition - the `left join` does that already. Just ensure that the `id` from the `left join`ed table is not `null` (in other words: there was a match in the `left join`).

If find that the logic might be more clearly expressed with `exists` than with a `left join`:

```
select
    case when "plm"."event" = 'newMessage' and exists (select 1 from voice_messages vm where plm.id = vm.id)
        then 'VoiceMessgae' 
        else plm."event" 
    end as "event" 
from others_messages plm
```